# Extracting pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose i have the following dataframe:

```
                                   Date      Open      High       Low     Close     Volume         min         max  Loc
Date
2020-06-15 14:00:00 2020-06-15 14:00:00  0.000123  0.000130  0.000121  0.000128  1467828.0  0.00012081  0.00013040    0
2020-06-15 18:00:00 2020-06-15 18:00:00  0.000128  0.000129  0.000123  0.000125  1264642.0           0           0    1
2020-06-15 22:00:00 2020-06-15 22:00:00  0.000125  0.000126  0.000122  0.000123   723738.0           0           0    2
```

I'm trying to create a new dataframe where:

1. The data should be the columns `Open`, `min`, `max` `Loc` but ONLY where `min` and `max` are > 0.
2. The index of the dataframe should be the column `Loc`

Now i know that to create a Dataframe from another dataframe i can use `pandas.concat()` but i don't know how to set the conditions i explained above. Can anyone help me out on this?

Expected output example:

```
 Loc    Open          min         max   
   0   0.000123    0.00012081  0.00013040
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by mask created by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) for compare for greater of both columns with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), select columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and last add [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.loc[df[['min','max']].gt(0).all(axis=1), ['Open','min','max','Loc']].set_index('Loc')
print (df)
         Open       min      max
Loc                             
0    0.000123  0.000121  0.00013
```

Or compare both columns separately and chain masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df = df.loc[df['min'].gt(0) & df['max'].gt(0), ['Open','min','max','Loc']].set_index('Loc')
```

EDIT:

Because error:

> ''>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int',

it means there are string repr of values in `min` or `max` columns (or both), so convert values to numbers before solutions above:

```
df['min'] = pd.to_numeric(df['min'], errors='coerce')
df['max'] = pd.to_numeric(df['max'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm getting the following error: ''>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', i suppose it has to do with the original dataframe. Maybe i need to convert everything to float or int?

Comment: @San9096 - I think it means `max` or `min` or both are strings repr. give me some tome for solution.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't notice that the column was in string format, to_numeric() should convert it

Comment: Yes, saw your edit and i was using the exact same line. Awesome! Thank you a lot. I accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Building your example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Date": ["2020-06-15 14:00:00", "2020-06-15 18:00:00", "2020-06-15 22:00:00"],
        "Open": [0.000123, 0.000128, 0.000125],
        "High": [0.000130, 0.000129, 0.000126],
        "Low": [0.000121, 0.000123, 0.000122],
        "Close": [0.000128, 0.000125, 0.000123],
        "Volume": [1467828.0, 1264642.0, 723738.0],
        "min": [0.00012081, 0, 0],
        "max": [0.00013040, 0, 0],
        "Loc":  [0, 1, 2],
    }
)

df.set_index("Date", drop=False, inplace=True)
```

A solution would be this:

```py
# Set the index to a different column
# ("df2" is a copy of "df")
df2 = df.set_index("Loc")

# Keep only some columns
df2 = df2[["Open", "min", "max"]]

# Filter rows based on a condition
df2 = df2[(df2["min"] > 0) & (df2["max"] > 0)]
```

`df2` would be like this:

```
         Open       min      max
Loc                             
0    0.000123  0.000121  0.00013
```